# How can I poll web requests without blocking?

Tags: perl

I have two web requests which I need to poll to find out when they return. Ideally I don't want to keep testing them in a tight loop. I would like to free up the CPU so other processes can execute.

I'm currently using Perl's Time::HiRes::sleep(0.100) function to release the CPU before testing whether or not the web requests have returned.

During testing under load I can see that the sleep duration 'stretches'. Ideally I want to make sure that the sleep duration is adhered to but that CPU is freed up. Should I be calling a different function to achieve this?

I'm coding Perl on Linux 2.6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than polling, see if you can't get file-descriptors and do a select call.

Then you'll get control back as soon as anything happens, without occupying the CPU at all.

Somewhere in the web-request will be some sockets, and attached to the sockets will be file-descriptors that you can use in select.

In any case your program can be interrupted at any point for any amount of time; if this is a real problem you need a real-time operating system, but since you're dealing with web-requests I doubt you need that level of responsiveness.

In fact what you want is a high level interface that does the select call for you. As suggested in the comments: http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Async/ looks like it'll do precisely what you need.

Comment: This is what HTTP::Async does under the hood - take a look at the code to see how it is done: http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Async/

Comment: This is precisely what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you really want an event loop.  There is
[POE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE),
[EV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?EV), and [abstraction layers over
both](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent).

Either way, don't implement this yourself.  This wheel has already
been invented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think sleep duration can be guaranteed on regular Linux. That's pretty much the point of a "Real Time" operating system, and regular Linux is not "Real Time."

I agree with @Douglas Leeder: use a select call to have the kernel notify you when something changes. You can also emulate sub-second sleeps with a select call, but Time::HiRes is a cleaner interface (and you're still not going to avoid stretching the wait).